# Determining the Number of Group Homomorphisms with a given pair of values $(x,g(x))$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

[image]

I think I can do all but the second one. It basically has to do with the fact that $|g(x)=y|$ divides $|x|$ 
So for example for $(x,y)=(117,52)=(26,3)$, we have $|x|=7$ but $|y|=49\nmid 7$. Similarly, for $(x,y)=(35,21)$, we have $|x|=13$ but $|y|=7\nmid 13$. Is this correct?

But what about the second one? I'm stuck...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, I found the answer. Since the value of $g(x)$ is completely determined by the value of the generator ($1$), we have $g(26)=g(26\times 1)=26g(1)=14\pmod {49}$. So we must find the number of possible values $z$ such that $26z=14\pmod {49}$, and that will correspond to the number of Homomorphisms with the given values. In this case it's $1$ ($z=42$).

For the general case, Given that $g(x)=y$ and $g:\mathbb Z_m\to \mathbb Z_n$

$g(x)=g(k\times 1)=kg(1)=y\pmod n$, for some $k$

We must find the number of possible values $z$ such that $kz=y\pmod {n}$, and that will correspond to the number of Homomorphisms with the given values